# get data from database in to text box c# asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i have grid view edit button , when user click edit the page will redirect to other page with textbox fields in url i was add {employee_ID} i want getdata from data base and put it in fields text box and when click edit it will edit in database

this gridview : http://prntscr.com/llgid0

and this is edit page with {Employee_ID} : http://prntscr.com/llgio4

html for edit page :

```
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <div>
            Employee ID :
            <asp:TextBox ID="id" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Employee Name : <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Address :
            <asp:TextBox ID="address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Birthdate :
            <asp:TextBox ID="birth" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Mobile No :<asp:TextBox ID="mobile" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Email :
            <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Country :<asp:TextBox ID="co" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            CityName :<asp:TextBox ID="city" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            UserName :<asp:TextBox ID="user" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Password :<asp:TextBox ID="pass" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Update" />
        </div>
    </form>

        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p class="auto-style1">
        &nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind in gridview page :

```
public partial class table : System.Web.UI.Page
{



    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlcon"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindEmpGrid();
            txtSearch.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void BindEmpGrid()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Emp", con);
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                grdEmp.DataSource = dt;
                grdEmp.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                grdEmp.DataSource = null;
                grdEmp.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
        }
        finally
        {
            dt.Clear();
            dt.Dispose();
            adp.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void ddlSearchBy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlSearchBy.SelectedItem.Text == "All")
        {
            txtSearch.Text = string.Empty;
            txtSearch.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            txtSearch.Enabled = true;
            txtSearch.Text = string.Empty;
            txtSearch.Focus();
        }
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            if (ddlSearchBy.SelectedItem.Text == "Employee_ID")
            {
                getEmpRecords(ddlSearchBy.SelectedItem.Text, txtSearch.Text.Trim());
            }
            else if (ddlSearchBy.SelectedItem.Text == "Employee_name")
            {
                getEmpRecords(ddlSearchBy.SelectedItem.Text, txtSearch.Text.Trim());
            }
            else if (ddlSearchBy.SelectedItem.Text == "Mobile")
            {
                getEmpRecords(ddlSearchBy.SelectedItem.Text, txtSearch.Text.Trim());
            }
            else
            {
                getEmpRecords(ddlSearchBy.SelectedItem.Text, txtSearch.Text.Trim());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
        }
        finally
        {
            dt.Clear();
            dt.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void getEmpRecords(string searchBy, string searchVal)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("all", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchBy", searchBy);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchVal", searchVal);
            adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                grdEmp.DataSource = dt;
                grdEmp.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                grdEmp.DataSource = dt;
                grdEmp.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
        }
        finally
        {
            dt.Clear();
            dt.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void grdEmp_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdEmp.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindEmpGrid();
    }

    protected void grdEmp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void grdEmp_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Del")
        {
            int EmpID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

            DeleteRecord(EmpID);
            BindEmpGrid();


        }
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            string EmpID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("update.aspx?Id="+ EmpID);



        }

    }


    private void DeleteRecord(int EmpID)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from Emp where Employee_ID = @a";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", EmpID);
        cmd.Connection = con;


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();


        }
}
```

Comment: so where's the problem?

Comment: How to get data according in query string in url from employee_ID and put it in filed textbox ? i want function to retrieve data depend on querystring from url , note : querystring number=Employee_id from data base

Comment: so you expect us to just write the code for you ?

Comment: at least have an attempt and we can help you when you get any errors

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect into other page with id then multiple solution available.

1) Using query string id fetch detail from database and fill value.

2)Store your data into session when you click on edit button and then fetch detail from your sessionid into other page/form.

```
public void fetchEmployeeDetail()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Emp where number =" + Request.QueryString["id"], con);
                adp.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    name.Text = dt.rows[0]["name"].ToString(); // name means your table column name 
                    address.Text = dt.rows[0]["name"].ToString();
                    birth.Text = dt.rows[0]["name"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes please wite for me code to fetch data from database and fill it in to textbox depend on employee_ID from query string in url number = 34 
please see pic :https://prnt.sc/llgio4

Comment: If you are publishing this project and want to use this code posted by 'user2156791': I would really recommend you to read about and learn how to use SQL parameters to secure your DB against SQL injections..

Comment: @Mohammed copy the connection string from your previous page and past in editpage and use it.

Comment: @heap1 For prevent sql injection we use session.

Comment: @Mohammed Replace rows to Rows. Also check where condition in query. Query like select * from Emp where Employee_id=" + Request.QueryString["id"]

Comment: @Mohammed a lot of people also know how to change values in their 'session value bag', it's not how you secure against sql injection. Also it looks like you are using the GET method and not session to pass the value you are directly concatenating with your sql query string..

Comment: when i click on edit : http://prntscr.com/llh0ve
data not retrieve depend on url query ID and fill data from database and put it in text box :http://prntscr.com/llh1kk

Comment: @Mohammed Please change sql query like  adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Emp where Employee_Id =" + Request.QueryString["Id"], con);

Comment: @Mohammed what is your Emp table primary key? Is Employee_Id or any thing else?

Comment: primary key is : ID

Comment: @Mohammed Work your solution or not?

Comment: @user2156791 not ! :(

Comment: @Mohammed What problem occure?